# Performing multiple inserts at once in oracle with ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, oracle, dbcommand

I'm trying to execute multiple inserts at once like this

```
var mydict =  new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };

var query = string.Join("; ", mydict.Select(x => $"insert into myTable (colA, colB) values ({x.Key},{x.Value})"));

using(var connection = new new OracleConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but i got `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-00911: invalid character'` even I can manually execute the generated query from sqldeveloper with no issues.

I alreay did this in the past with sqlserver and sqlite, and i had no issues.

why this happens? is there a cleaner way?

---

here is the generated sql:

```
insert into myTable (colA, colB) values (72520,2452); insert into myTable (colA, colB) values (73293,2453)
```

Comment: String concatenation (even if hidden in `String.Format`) should never be used to insert values in SQL. Always parameterise you queries.

Comment: And, what is the SQL you are sending: copy from debugger into the question please.

Comment: Oracle does not allow multiple statements to be executed in one command. SQL developer will split your string into multiple statements and execute each in turn.

Comment: Try *anonymous block*: `var query = "begin " + string.Join("; ", mydict...) + " end;"`

Comment: add ; at the end, every insert needs the terminator

Comment: If you have *very many* inserts, the "cleaner" way is a bulk copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of *Oracle* you should generate *anonymous block*, e.g.:

```
 begin -- wrap in begin .. end
   insert into myTable (colA, colB) values (72520, 2452); 
   insert into myTable (colA, colB) values (73293, 2453); -- do not forget last ;
 end;
```

In your case

```
var query = 
  "begin " + 
     string.Join("; ", mydict
       .Select(x => $"insert into myTable (colA, colB) values ({x.Key},{x.Value})")) + 
  "; end;";
```

**Disclaimer:** Do not do this (but implement `bulk insert`, see *MT0* answer) if

1. You have to insert strings (*SQL injection*)
2. You have a lot of records to insert (bulk operations work *faster*)
3. You perform the call frequently (*hard parsing*, see https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables)

Comment: If the key and/or value was a string then this opens the query up to SQL Injection.

Comment: @MT0: quite right, there're at least **3** reasons not doing via anonymous block generation but with bulk insert. I've only wanted to amend the code in the question

Comment: i need this just for a small one-time-use internal script to move data to a test db, no real dangers :)

Answer (score 2):

That is not the way you should do it. The preferred way would be like this:

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "insert into myTable (colA, colB) values (:ColA, :ColB)";
command.Parameters.Add("ColA", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Input);
command.Parameters.Add("ColB", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Input);

foreach ( var entry in mydict ) {
   command.Parameters["ColA"].Value = entry.Key;
   command.Parameters["ColA"].Value = entry.Value;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> why this happens?

Oracle does not allow multiple statements to be executed in one command.

SQL developer will split your string into multiple statements and execute each in turn running them as multiple commands,

> is there a cleaner way?

Use a batch/bulk insert:

- [Bulk Insert to Oracle using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/343299/1509264)
- [ORA-00604 error while batch insertion inside TransactionScope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33517597/1509264)
- [OracleBulkCopy does not insert entries to table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17939893/1509264)

This way you can use bind values and are not building your insert statement as one huge string.

Comment: In *general case* (a lot of data, not necessary ints, frequent calls) it the solution we should use